# Make text appear on click

Tags: flutter, button, dart

I am trying to make some text appear, where there was no text before. It should happen on the click of a button. The button should change a `bool` variable too `true` so that something like an `if` statement can then validate if the button was clicked. The code for the button looks like this:

```
child: GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
     ButtonPushed = true;
   }
 ...
```

But I have no idea how to create a statement, that checks if `ButtonPushed` equals `true` and only then execute the lines of code that display the text somewhere above the button on the screen.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `StatefulWidget`. Store `_clicked` state on state and change it when button is pressed. On build method show or hide based on value of `_clicked`.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _clicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_clicked) Text('Button is clicked'),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _clicked = true;
                });
              },
              child: Text('Click me')
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To show/hide Text I'm simply using `if (condition) Widget(),`. Because widget is placed inside Widget list (Column's children property accepts widget list). You could als use something like that:

```dart
child: _clicked ? Text('clicked') : null,
```

If this code crashes because of widget doesn't accepts null child you could try this:

```dart
child: _clicked ? Text('clicked') : SizedBox(),
```

Check flutter reference:

- [Adding interactivity to your Flutter app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)

Comment: Great! It works. I have just missed to add the setState() under the onPressed(). Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do :

```
bool myBool = false;
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      myBool = !myBool;
    });
  },
  child: Text(
    "Press me",
  ),
),
Visibility(
visible : myBool,
child: Text("Hello"),
    )
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/FirasDev/pen/KKdGweJ) of it working.